# Where should I put function which would be used by two or more Vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function which takes an ID as an argument and finds the object to which this ID belongs from a JSON that is stored in the Vuex store. So far I have used the function in 1 component only, however, I recently created a second component which also requires that function. Currently I have just copied and pasted the function, however, this seems to be less than optimal. This is why I wonder where should this function be placed so that it's accessible from all components that need it.

I've been wondering if the Vuex store is a viable place to store the function but I'm not too sure so I decided to ask for your advice. Thanks

```
findChampionName(id){
    let championId = id.toString();
    let champion = Object.entries(this.$store.state.champions).find(([key,value]) => value.key === championId);

    return champion[1]
}
```

Vuex store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        champions: null
    },
    mutations: {
        champions(state, data){
            state.champions = data.champions
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getChampions({commit, state}){
            axios.get("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.14.1/data/en_US/champion.json")
            .then((response) => {
                commit('champions', {
                    champions: response.data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can see, you should use a vuex getter for your case:

```
getters: {
    getChampionName => state => id => {
        let championId = id.toString();
        let champion = Object.entries(state.champions).find(([key,value]) => value.key === championId);

        return champion[1]
    }
}
```

> And you can access that getter by passing the id: `this.$store.getters['findChampionName'](id)`

Comment: Yes those getters seem to be perfect for my case. Thanks